# HMAC-SHA-512 implemention for ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, hmac, sha512

As mentioned by the title, I would like to find an implementation for HMAC-SHA-512 written for ActionScript. I was able to find a library that provide HMAC-SHA-256 with other functions, however, I am looking for HMAC-SHA-512 specifically.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Or, since actionscript and javascript have the same origin, can some one port this javascript version into actionscript?

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html

**Edit 2:**

I already ported the code from javascript to actionscript. The code can be found in one of the answers in this question
[Porting SHA-512 Javascript implementation to Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267873/porting-sha512-javascript-implemention-to-actionscript)

Comment: You can find optimazed code [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931980/as3-air-app-with-hmacsha512-encryption). Look HMACSHA512.as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation you link to doesn't seem to be using any features that aren't supported by ActionScript 3. Just surround the whole thing with `public class SHA512 { }`, and prefix the first five functions with `public`.

**Edit:** You will also need to convert `function int64` to it's own class (or possibly use `Number`, though I'm not sure if you will lose precision for 64-bit integers).

Comment: True, at the beginning, the modification seems easy. However, as I made Int64 as a class, modified the other functions to be part of it, and tried to adjust the other parts accordingly, the work didnt compile

Comment: Thanks man, everything is fixed now and the code is working properly. I will post a link to the ported code in the question as an edit and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this library:
http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Though only does:
SHA-256,SHA-224,SHA-1,MD5, and MD2

So I guess that doesn't answer your question.

But best Crypto library for actionscript I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Just found all of SHA-2 (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512) implemented at http://code.google.com/p/flame/. Also it provides HMAC implementation. Didn't try it yet but looks what you're looking for.