# Porting SHA512 Javascript implemention to Actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, porting, sha512

I am wondering if anyone can help me in porting a SHA-512 implemention in Javascript to Actionscript. Since both Javascript and Actionscript share the same origin, I think porting it will be easy for people who are used to Actionscript.

The code for sha512 in javascript can be found here:

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html

Thank you.

Comment: You asked this question yesterday...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261454/hmac-sha-512-implemention-for-actionscript

Comment: true, but the question was about finding an implemented version of it, not porting from another language. Anyway, I already ported the code and it is posted below

Comment: You can find optimazed code [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931980/as3-air-app-with-hmacsha512-encryption). Look HMACSHA512.as

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code ported by me. The code is separated between two files Int64.as and Sha512.as, both of them belong to the com.crypto package.

com/crypto/Int64.as

```
/*
 * Int64 for ActionScript
 * Ported by: AAA
 * Ported from: See below
 */

/*
 * A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-512, as defined
 * in FIPS 180-2
 * Version 2.2 Copyright Anonymous Contributor, Paul Johnston 2000 - 2009.
 * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
 * Distributed under the BSD License
 * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for details.
 */

package com.crypto {
    public class Int64 {
        public var h;
        public var l;

        public function Int64(h, l) {
            this.h = h;
            this.l = l;
        }

        public function copy(src) {
            this.h = src.h;
            this.l = src.l;
        }

        public function rrot(x, shift) {
            this.l = (x.l >>> shift) | (x.h << (32-shift));
            this.h = (x.h >>> shift) | (x.l << (32-shift));
        }

        public function revrrot(x, shift) {
            this.l = (x.h >>> shift) | (x.l << (32-shift));
            this.h = (x.l >>> shift) | (x.h << (32-shift));
        }

        public function shr(x, shift) {
            this.l = (x.l >>> shift) | (x.h << (32-shift));
            this.h = (x.h >>> shift);
        }

        public function add(x, y) {
            var w0 = (x.l & 0xffff) + (y.l & 0xffff);
            var w1 = (x.l >>> 16) + (y.l >>> 16) + (w0 >>> 16);
            var w2 = (x.h & 0xffff) + (y.h & 0xffff) + (w1 >>> 16);
            var w3 = (x.h >>> 16) + (y.h >>> 16) + (w2 >>> 16);
            this.l = (w0 & 0xffff) | (w1 << 16);
            this.h = (w2 & 0xffff) | (w3 << 16);
        }

        public function add4(a, b, c, d) {
            var w0 = (a.l & 0xffff) + (b.l & 0xffff) + (c.l & 0xffff) + (d.l & 0xffff);
            var w1 = (a.l >>> 16) + (b.l >>> 16) + (c.l >>> 16) + (d.l >>> 16) + (w0 >>> 16);
            var w2 = (a.h & 0xffff) + (b.h & 0xffff) + (c.h & 0xffff) + (d.h & 0xffff) + (w1 >>> 16);
            var w3 = (a.h >>> 16) + (b.h >>> 16) + (c.h >>> 16) + (d.h >>> 16) + (w2 >>> 16);
            this.l = (w0 & 0xffff) | (w1 << 16);
            this.h = (w2 & 0xffff) | (w3 << 16);
        }

        public function add5(a, b, c, d, e) {
            var w0 = (a.l & 0xffff) + (b.l & 0xffff) + (c.l & 0xffff) + (d.l & 0xffff) + (e.l & 0xffff);
            var w1 = (a.l >>> 16) + (b.l >>> 16) + (c.l >>> 16) + (d.l >>> 16) + (e.l >>> 16) + (w0 >>> 16);
            var w2 = (a.h & 0xffff) + (b.h & 0xffff) + (c.h & 0xffff) + (d.h & 0xffff) + (e.h & 0xffff) + (w1 >>> 16);
            var w3 = (a.h >>> 16) + (b.h >>> 16) + (c.h >>> 16) + (d.h >>> 16) + (e.h >>> 16) + (w2 >>> 16);
            this.l = (w0 & 0xffff) | (w1 << 16);
            this.h = (w2 & 0xffff) | (w3 << 16);
        }
    }
}
```

com/crypto/Sha512.as

```
/*
 * SHA-512 for ActionScript
 * Ported by: AAA
 * Ported from: See below
 */

/*
 * A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-512, as defined
 * in FIPS 180-2
 * Version 2.2 Copyright Anonymous Contributor, Paul Johnston 2000 - 2009.
 * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
 * Distributed under the BSD License
 * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for details.
 */

package com.crypto {
    public class Sha512 {
        public var hexcase = 0;
        public var b64pad  = "";

        public function Sha512() {
        }

        public function hex_sha512(s) { return rstr2hex(rstr_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(s))); }
        public function b64_sha512(s) { return rstr2b64(rstr_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(s))); }
        public function any_sha512(s, e) { return rstr2any(rstr_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(s)), e);}
        public function hex_hmac_sha512(k, d) { return rstr2hex(rstr_hmac_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(k), str2rstr_utf8(d))); }
        public function b64_hmac_sha512(k, d) { return rstr2b64(rstr_hmac_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(k), str2rstr_utf8(d))); }
        public function any_hmac_sha512(k, d, e) { return rstr2any(rstr_hmac_sha512(str2rstr_utf8(k), str2rstr_utf8(d)), e);}

        public function sha512_vm_test() {
            return hex_sha512("abc").toLowerCase() == "ddaf35a193617abacc417349ae20413112e6fa4e89a97ea20a9eeee64b55d39a"
                                                    + "2192992a274fc1a836ba3c23a3feebbd454d4423643ce80e2a9ac94fa54ca49f";
        }

        private function rstr_sha512(s) {
            return binb2rstr(binb_sha512(rstr2binb(s), s.length * 8));
        }

        private function rstr_hmac_sha512(key, data) {
            var bkey = rstr2binb(key);
            if(bkey.length > 32) bkey = binb_sha512(bkey, key.length * 8);

            var ipad = new Array(32)
            var opad = new Array(32);
            for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
                opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
            }

            var hash = binb_sha512(ipad.concat(rstr2binb(data)), 1024 + data.length * 8);
            return binb2rstr(binb_sha512(opad.concat(hash), 1024 + 512));
        }

        private function rstr2hex(input) {
            try { hexcase } catch(e) { hexcase=0; }
            var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
            var output = "";
            var x;
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                x = input.charCodeAt(i);
                output += hex_tab.charAt((x >>> 4) & 0x0F) + hex_tab.charAt(x & 0x0F);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private function rstr2b64(input)
        {
            try { b64pad } catch(e) { b64pad=''; }
            var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
            var output = "";
            var len = input.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 3) {
                var triplet = (input.charCodeAt(i) << 16)
                | (i + 1 < len ? input.charCodeAt(i+1) << 8 : 0)
                | (i + 2 < len ? input.charCodeAt(i+2)      : 0);
                for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    if(i * 8 + j * 6 > input.length * 8) output += b64pad;
                    else output += tab.charAt((triplet >>> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
                }
            }
            return output;
        }

        private function rstr2any(input, encoding) {
            var divisor = encoding.length;
            var i, j, q, x, quotient;

            var dividend = new Array(Math.ceil(input.length / 2));
            for(i = 0; i < dividend.length; i++) {
                dividend[i] = (input.charCodeAt(i * 2) << 8) | input.charCodeAt(i * 2 + 1);
            }

            var full_length = Math.ceil(input.length * 8 / (Math.log(encoding.length) / Math.log(2)));
            var remainders = new Array(full_length);
            for(j = 0; j < full_length; j++) {
                quotient = new Array();
                x = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < dividend.length; i++) {
                    x = (x << 16) + dividend[i];
                    q = Math.floor(x / divisor);
                    x -= q * divisor;
                    if(quotient.length > 0 || q > 0)
                        quotient[quotient.length] = q;
                }
                remainders[j] = x;
                dividend = quotient;
            }

            var output = "";
            for(i = remainders.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                output += encoding.charAt(remainders[i]);
            return output;
        }

        private function str2rstr_utf8(input) {
            var output = "";
            var i = -1;
            var x, y;

            while(++i < input.length) {
                x = input.charCodeAt(i);
                y = i + 1 < input.length ? input.charCodeAt(i + 1) : 0;
                if(0xD800 <= x && x <= 0xDBFF && 0xDC00 <= y && y <= 0xDFFF) {
                    x = 0x10000 + ((x & 0x03FF) << 10) + (y & 0x03FF);
                    i++;
                }

                if(x <= 0x7F)
                    output += String.fromCharCode(x);
                else if(x <= 0x7FF)
                    output += String.fromCharCode(0xC0 | ((x >>> 6 ) & 0x1F), 0x80 | ( x         & 0x3F));
                else if(x <= 0xFFFF)
                    output += String.fromCharCode(0xE0 | ((x >>> 12) & 0x0F),
                                    0x80 | ((x >>> 6 ) & 0x3F),
                                    0x80 | ( x         & 0x3F));
                else if(x <= 0x1FFFFF)
                    output += String.fromCharCode(0xF0 | ((x >>> 18) & 0x07),
                                    0x80 | ((x >>> 12) & 0x3F),
                                    0x80 | ((x >>> 6 ) & 0x3F),
                                    0x80 | ( x         & 0x3F));
            }

            return output;
        }

        private function str2rstr_utf16le(input) {
            var output = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
                output += String.fromCharCode( input.charCodeAt(i)        & 0xFF,
                                  (input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF);
            return output;
        }

        private function str2rstr_utf16be(input) {
            var output = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
                output += String.fromCharCode((input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF,
                                   input.charCodeAt(i)        & 0xFF);
            return output;
        }

        private function rstr2binb(input) {
            var output = new Array(input.length >> 2);
            for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
                output[i] = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length * 8; i += 8)
                output[i>>5] |= (input.charCodeAt(i / 8) & 0xFF) << (24 - i % 32);
            return output;
        }

        private function binb2rstr(input) {
            var output = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length * 32; i += 8)
                output += String.fromCharCode((input[i>>5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & 0xFF);
            return output;
        }

        var sha512_k;

        private function binb_sha512(x, len) {
            if(sha512_k == undefined) {
                sha512_k = new Array(
                    new Int64(0x428a2f98, -685199838), new Int64(0x71374491, 0x23ef65cd),
                    new Int64(-1245643825, -330482897), new Int64(-373957723, -2121671748),
                    new Int64(0x3956c25b, -213338824), new Int64(0x59f111f1, -1241133031),
                    new Int64(-1841331548, -1357295717), new Int64(-1424204075, -630357736),
                    new Int64(-670586216, -1560083902), new Int64(0x12835b01, 0x45706fbe),
                    new Int64(0x243185be, 0x4ee4b28c), new Int64(0x550c7dc3, -704662302),
                    new Int64(0x72be5d74, -226784913), new Int64(-2132889090, 0x3b1696b1),
                    new Int64(-1680079193, 0x25c71235), new Int64(-1046744716, -815192428),
                    new Int64(-459576895, -1628353838), new Int64(-272742522, 0x384f25e3),
                    new Int64(0xfc19dc6, -1953704523), new Int64(0x240ca1cc, 0x77ac9c65),
                    new Int64(0x2de92c6f, 0x592b0275), new Int64(0x4a7484aa, 0x6ea6e483),
                    new Int64(0x5cb0a9dc, -1119749164), new Int64(0x76f988da, -2096016459),
                    new Int64(-1740746414, -295247957), new Int64(-1473132947, 0x2db43210),
                    new Int64(-1341970488, -1728372417), new Int64(-1084653625, -1091629340),
                    new Int64(-958395405, 0x3da88fc2), new Int64(-710438585, -1828018395),
                    new Int64(0x6ca6351, -536640913), new Int64(0x14292967, 0xa0e6e70),
                    new Int64(0x27b70a85, 0x46d22ffc), new Int64(0x2e1b2138, 0x5c26c926),
                    new Int64(0x4d2c6dfc, 0x5ac42aed), new Int64(0x53380d13, -1651133473),
                    new Int64(0x650a7354, -1951439906), new Int64(0x766a0abb, 0x3c77b2a8),
                    new Int64(-2117940946, 0x47edaee6), new Int64(-1838011259, 0x1482353b),
                    new Int64(-1564481375, 0x4cf10364), new Int64(-1474664885, -1136513023),
                    new Int64(-1035236496, -789014639), new Int64(-949202525, 0x654be30),
                    new Int64(-778901479, -688958952), new Int64(-694614492, 0x5565a910),
                    new Int64(-200395387, 0x5771202a), new Int64(0x106aa070, 0x32bbd1b8),
                    new Int64(0x19a4c116, -1194143544), new Int64(0x1e376c08, 0x5141ab53),
                    new Int64(0x2748774c, -544281703), new Int64(0x34b0bcb5, -509917016),
                    new Int64(0x391c0cb3, -976659869), new Int64(0x4ed8aa4a, -482243893),
                    new Int64(0x5b9cca4f, 0x7763e373), new Int64(0x682e6ff3, -692930397),
                    new Int64(0x748f82ee, 0x5defb2fc), new Int64(0x78a5636f, 0x43172f60),
                    new Int64(-2067236844, -1578062990), new Int64(-1933114872, 0x1a6439ec),
                    new Int64(-1866530822, 0x23631e28), new Int64(-1538233109, -561857047),
                    new Int64(-1090935817, -1295615723), new Int64(-965641998, -479046869),
                    new Int64(-903397682, -366583396), new Int64(-779700025, 0x21c0c207),
                    new Int64(-354779690, -840897762), new Int64(-176337025, -294727304),
                    new Int64(0x6f067aa, 0x72176fba), new Int64(0xa637dc5, -1563912026),
                    new Int64(0x113f9804, -1090974290), new Int64(0x1b710b35, 0x131c471b),
                    new Int64(0x28db77f5, 0x23047d84), new Int64(0x32caab7b, 0x40c72493),
                    new Int64(0x3c9ebe0a, 0x15c9bebc), new Int64(0x431d67c4, -1676669620),
                    new Int64(0x4cc5d4be, -885112138), new Int64(0x597f299c, -60457430),
                    new Int64(0x5fcb6fab, 0x3ad6faec), new Int64(0x6c44198c, 0x4a475817));
            }

            var H = new Array(
                new Int64(0x6a09e667, -205731576),
                new Int64(-1150833019, -2067093701),
                new Int64(0x3c6ef372, -23791573),
                new Int64(-1521486534, 0x5f1d36f1),
                new Int64(0x510e527f, -1377402159),
                new Int64(-1694144372, 0x2b3e6c1f),
                new Int64(0x1f83d9ab, -79577749),
                new Int64(0x5be0cd19, 0x137e2179));

            var T1 = new Int64(0, 0),
            T2 = new Int64(0, 0),
            a = new Int64(0,0),
            b = new Int64(0,0),
            c = new Int64(0,0),
            d = new Int64(0,0),
            e = new Int64(0,0),
            f = new Int64(0,0),
            g = new Int64(0,0),
            h = new Int64(0,0),

            s0 = new Int64(0, 0),
            s1 = new Int64(0, 0),
            Ch = new Int64(0, 0),
            Maj = new Int64(0, 0),
            r1 = new Int64(0, 0),
            r2 = new Int64(0, 0),
            r3 = new Int64(0, 0);
            var j, i;
            var W = new Array(80);
            for(i=0; i<80; i++)
                W[i] = new Int64(0, 0);

            x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - (len & 0x1f));
            x[((len + 128 >> 10)<< 5) + 31] = len;

            for(i = 0; i<x.length; i+=32) {
                a.copy(H[0]);
                b.copy(H[1]);
                c.copy(H[2]);
                d.copy(H[3]);
                e.copy(H[4]);
                f.copy(H[5]);
                g.copy(H[6]);
                h.copy(H[7]);

                for(j=0; j<16; j++) {
                    W[j].h = x[i + 2*j];
                    W[j].l = x[i + 2*j + 1];
                }

                for(j=16; j<80; j++) {
                    r1.rrot(W[j-2], 19);
                    r2.revrrot(W[j-2], 29);
                    r3.shr(W[j-2], 6);
                    s1.l = r1.l ^ r2.l ^ r3.l;
                    s1.h = r1.h ^ r2.h ^ r3.h;

                    r1.rrot(W[j-15], 1);
                    r2.rrot(W[j-15], 8);
                    r3.shr(W[j-15], 7);
                    s0.l = r1.l ^ r2.l ^ r3.l;
                    s0.h = r1.h ^ r2.h ^ r3.h;

                    W[j].add4(s1, W[j-7], s0, W[j-16]);
                }

                for(j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                    Ch.l = (e.l & f.l) ^ (~e.l & g.l);
                    Ch.h = (e.h & f.h) ^ (~e.h & g.h);

                    r1.rrot(e, 14);
                    r2.rrot(e, 18);
                    r3.revrrot(e, 9);
                    s1.l = r1.l ^ r2.l ^ r3.l;
                    s1.h = r1.h ^ r2.h ^ r3.h;

                    r1.rrot(a, 28);
                    r2.revrrot(a, 2);
                    r3.revrrot(a, 7);
                    s0.l = r1.l ^ r2.l ^ r3.l;
                    s0.h = r1.h ^ r2.h ^ r3.h;

                    Maj.l = (a.l & b.l) ^ (a.l & c.l) ^ (b.l & c.l);
                    Maj.h = (a.h & b.h) ^ (a.h & c.h) ^ (b.h & c.h);

                    T1.add5(h, s1, Ch, sha512_k[j], W[j]);
                    T2.add(s0, Maj);

                    h.copy(g);
                    g.copy(f);
                    f.copy(e);
                    e.add(d, T1);
                    d.copy(c);
                    c.copy(b);
                    b.copy(a);
                    a.add(T1, T2);
                }

                H[0].add(H[0], a);
                H[1].add(H[1], b);
                H[2].add(H[2], c);
                H[3].add(H[3], d);
                H[4].add(H[4], e);
                H[5].add(H[5], f);
                H[6].add(H[6], g);
                H[7].add(H[7], h);
            }

            var hash = new Array(16);
            for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
                hash[2*i] = H[i].h;
                hash[2*i + 1] = H[i].l;
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I could not find a proper place to upload them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to post a comment on the above (where this should be), but there is an error with some signatures using this code due to Actionscript's imaginative behaviour when appending the null character to a string (it doesn't).

For a quick and dirty fix to the hex encoded hmac which is what I am using, I changed the hex_hmac_sha512 function (just for the encoding it calls) and added a binb2hex function as follows:

```
    private function hex_hmac_sha512(key, data) {
        key = str2rstr_utf8(key);
        data = str2rstr_utf8(data);
        var bkey = rstr2binb(key);
        if(bkey.length > 32) bkey = binb_sha512(bkey, key.length * 8);

        var ipad = new Array(32)
        var opad = new Array(32);
        for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
                opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
        }

        var hash = binb_sha512(ipad.concat(rstr2binb(data)), 1024 + data.length * 8);
        return binb2hex(binb_sha512(opad.concat(hash), 1024 + 512));
}

private function binb2hex(input) {
    var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";        
    var output = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length * 32; i += 8){
            var schar = (input[i>>5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & 0xFF;
            output += hex_tab.charAt((schar >>> 4) & 0x0F) + hex_tab.charAt(schar & 0x0F);              
    }
    return output;      
}
```