# errors, incorrect values when comparing sha512 as3, with vb.net

Tags: actionscript-3, cryptography

ive been testing an sha512 class. i need to generate a hash from a string within flash cs5, but i need it to match the hash produced by asp.net(vb). it appears to be adding a zero somewhere in the string, and i dont know why.

these are the files im using: [Porting SHA512 Javascript implemention to Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267873/porting-sha512-javascript-implemention-to-actionscript).

the hashed string is the name "Karla" in this example

example (asp.net)// ** the brackets show where the difference is ** C4DB628AD520AFF7308ED19E91635E8E24A6C7CFD4DB2F71BBE2FA6CD63770B315A839143037BB9DB16784C0BDCEB622ECAA4077D4D8(1787)D5023E86734748

(as3)

C4DB628AD520AFF7308ED19E91635E8E24A6C7CFD4DB2F71BBE2FA6CD63770B315A839143037BB9DB16784C0BDCEB622ECAA4077D4D8(17087)D5023E86734748

there's added info below, in the link i provided, but i do not think it related to what i need, i dont think im using hmac, just a straight string hash, however, when i do it in vb.net i get the bytes from the string first the i has the bytes.

I had a feeling that the as3 code converted the string automatically in the sha512 class?

hoping someone came across this issue as well.

thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of those hashes are correct. The correct SHA512 hash for the string "Karla" is:

```
C4DB628AD520AFF7308ED19E91635E8E24A6C7CFD4DB2F71BBE2FA6CD63770B315A839143037BB9DB16784C0BDCEB622ECAA4077D4D817087D5023E867347408
```

However, I would wager that the AS3 hash is actually correct -- the javascript version generates the correct hash, [see here](http://jsbin.com/ulatax/1) -- and was just pasted incorrectly.

In two places in the computed hash, it contains the byte `0x08`, but in the ASP.NET version high 4 bits of the byte are being lost, and its being appended to the output string as just `"8"` not `"08"`.

Basically, your ASP.NET hash generator is trashing numbers less than `0x10` -- ignoring the leading zero -- and giving you malformed hashes..

Another way to tell that there is something amiss with your ASP.NET hash is that its only 126 characters (504 hex encoded bits) long.